# How to call package from php having procedure in oracle using oci drivers?

Tags: php, oracle, package, call

I am calling oracle package having procedure using oci drivers. 
I am getting error as

> Warning: oci_execute() [function.oci-execute]: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_BRAND_MODEL_LIST' ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored in /opt/lampp/htdocs/call.php on line 26

All parameters are correct.
`$p_contract_no = '11-col1-cm';`
`$p_utilityagencyname='ATM';`
`$p_appliance_type='BO';`
`$p_tier_type=1;`
`$p_brand_code =NULL;`
`$p_execution_type='brand';`
`$query="begin process_101.get_brand_model_list(:p_contract_no, :p_utilityagencyname, :p_appliance_type, :p_tier_type, :p_brand_code, :p_execution_type, :r); end;";`
`$stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);`
`oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":p_contract_no", & $p_contract_no);`
`oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":p_utilityagencyname", & $p_utilityagencyname);`
`oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":p_appliance_type", & $p_appliance_type);`
`oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":p_tier_type", & $p_tier_type);`
`oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":p_brand_code", & $p_brand_code);`
`oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":p_execution_type", & $p_execution_type);`
`oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":r", $r);`
`oci_execute($stid);`
please help if anyone have solution to my problem. Thanks in advance..

Comment: How is the procedure defined, specifically, what are the parameter definitions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle Stored Procedure call by PhP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211652/oracle-stored-procedure-call-by-php)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember you have to specify `type` and `maxlength` to [`oci_bind_by_name()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php) for variables returned from the procedure.

Assuming `:r` is the `OUT` variable, try:

```
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":r", $r, 50, SQLT_CHR);
```

The following code works for returning a value from an Oracle procedure ([Zend_Db_Adapter_Oracle](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html) version):

```
$statement = $db->prepare('BEGIN oracle_procedure(:result); END;');
$statement->bindParam('result', $result, SQLT_CHR, 12);
$statement->execute();
echo $result;
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, but i am working with package having procedure with custom type "table of"

Comment: There was the problem with datatype (Array of objects). php doesn't support array of objects. so this change need to be done at oracle end. Response from oracle is converted to string with record separator and my problem get resolved.