# PHP: calling Oracle stored proc that returns a table

Tags: php, oracle, plsql

I have an Oracle stored proc that takes 2 parameters. `userid` as an input parameter and an Oracle table with 2 columns as second out parameter. How can I invoke the procedure from PHP? I think that the problem stands in the `oci_bind_*` for the second parameter. I've tried `oci_bind_array_by_name` but I always get `PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to GET_VALUES`.
Can anyone help me, please?

Here is my code:

```
$tab=array();
$query = "begin GET_VALUES(:P_CUSTOMERCODE,:P_TAB); end;";
$stmt = oci_parse($ora_conn, $query) or die(oci_error());
oci_bind_by_name($stmt,":P_CUSTOMERCODE",$codUtente,255);
oci_bind_array_by_name($stmt,":P_TAB",$tab,100,100,SQLT_CHR);
oci_execute($stmt) or die(oci_error());
```

Comment: What's your code so far?

Answer (score 0):

This might answer your problem: [How to call package from php having procedure in oracle using oci drivers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750797/how-to-call-package-from-php-having-procedure-in-oracle-using-oci-drivers)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure a multi-column table will work with oci_bind_array_by_name.  Looking at the php manual, you can use this to bind a simple varray, assoc array or nested table, basically as simply 1 column list of values.  You'd specify the type of array in the "type" param, using SQLT_CHR for varchar2 for example (if you defined an array like : `type t_array is table of varchar2(100) index by pls_integer`).

Seems you created a custom table of a custom record type(?), something like:

```
type t_rec is record (
col1 number,
col2 varchar2(100)
);
type t_tab is table of t_rec;
```

I don't see where you can bind to t_tab as an out param using php's oci8 calls, but I may be mistaken.